# Existence of elements of order $p^k$ in a finite group

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

By Cauchy's theorem, if a prime number $p$ divides the order of a group $G$, then there is an element $g$ in $G$ whose order is $p$. In addition, if $|G|$ admits a prime decomposition with a factor $p^k$, then Sylow's theorem tells us that a subgroup of order $p^k$ must exist.

My question is the following. If $|G|$ admits a prime decomposition with a factor $p^k$, does this imply that an element of order $p^k$ must exist in $G$?

**Update:** As explained in Mindlack's answer (among others), the implication does not hold and simple counterexamples exist. In the comments, Mindlack discusses special cases where such an element exists.

Comment: It's good to keep small examples of finite groups in mind.  Here, the non-cyclic group of order $4$ is already a counterexample.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, because that would imply that $G$ has a cyclic Sylow subgroup, which is not always true. A simple example: $G=\mathbb{F}_p^2$ for addition.

Comment: Your answer seem to suggest that such an element could however exist in some cases. If we restrict G to be the symmetric group (of any order), would your answer change? (If so, I'll update the question accordingly.) Thanks.

Comment: if $n$ is large enough and $p$ is any prime factor of $n!$ (say, $p < n/2$), the corresponding $p$-Sylow has cardinality $p^k$, where $k>n/p -1$. To have an element of corresponding order, you need that $p^k \leq n$. If this holds, then $k \geq 2$ thus $n \geq p^2$ hence by Legendre $k \geq n/p$ and $n \geq p^k > kp \geq n$. Thus, in a symmetric group $S_n$, there is a cyclic $p$-Sylow iff $p > n/2$, when, say, $n \geq 5$.

Answer (score 2):

No, $G= C_p \times \cdots \times C_p$ ($k$ factors) has order $p^k$ but all nontrivial elements have order $p$.

Answer (score 1):

No. $\mathbb{Z}_2 \oplus \mathbb{Z}_2$ has order $2^2$ but no elements of order $2^2$.