# In a group of order $m p^n$ for $p$ prime, if $k<n$, is there an element of order $p^k$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, sylow-theory

Let $G$ a group of order $mp^n$ where $p$ is prime. Let $k\leq n$. Is there an element of order $p^k$ ?

---

Since $p$ divide $|G|$, by Cauchy theorem, there is $g\in G$ s.t. $g$ has order $p$. I can't do better. I tried to use the fact that there is a $p-$Sylow group, but it just confirm the fact that there is an element of order $p$, not of order $p^k$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, for instance when $G=\mathbb{F}_p^3$, every element has order $p$.

Comment: You gave the "same" answer 9 hours ago [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3037841/existence-of-elements-of-order-pk-in-a-finite-group).